# what is the index of a subgroup generated by -1

Tags: group-theory

I was told that the index of a subgroup generated by $k$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ with normal addition is $k$. But what about when k is a negative number like $-1$?
Intuitively I thought it was $2$, but am I right? How do I justify this answer?
Many thanks to you.

Answer (score 2):

Answer: It's the same as the group generated by $|k|$

Hint for a proof: Any group containing $-k$ contains $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not right. Hint: $-1$ is a generator of $\mathbb Z$.